# How do I get validation errors from Angular Material Datepicker when using reactive forms?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, angular2-forms

I am trying to get validation errors from the DatePicker control using reactive forms. I'm having a few issues.

1) DatePicker doesn't update the control value until a digit is entered

2) I don't see any way to get validation errors. The component itself has a validate method, but the form control doesn't have access to the component.

Has anyone been able to get this to work with their reactive forms?

Comment: Have you read the [**docs**](https://material.angular.io/components/component/datepicker)?

Comment: Yes, several times

Comment: I get stuck as well with the "enter-a-digit-to-validate" limitation that does not even work with MomentAdapter : as long as there is a digit in the input, `moment` says the date is valid ... too bad!

Comment: Have you been able to solve this?

Comment: I don't recall the issue that prompted the question and this control has changed a lot over the last year. I'd probably make a new question. I'm able to get min/max validation via myFormGroup.get('myDateControl').errors['matDatepickerMax']